# How would you do this using SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table `table1` with the following structure:

```
  id date v1   v2  v3  v4 ... vn
  ------------------------------
  1   03   Y    N  89  77 ... x
  1   04   N    N  9   7  ... i
  1   05   N    Y  6   90 ... j
  1   06   N    Y  9   34 ... i
  1   07   N    Y  0   88 ... i
  2   03   N    N  9   77 ... f
  2   04   Y    Y  90  7  ... y
  2   05   Y    N  6   90 ... v
  2   06   N    Y  9   34 ... i
  2   07   N    N  10  88 ... i
```

As you might see, the table has five rows for each id. I'd like to create two new columns:

-summarystory:= This variable is computed for those rows having the date between `05` and `07` and is the sum of the variable v3 for the last three rows.

Let me explain this better: the first two rows (`date` 03 and 04) must have `NULL` values, but the row having `date=05` is the sum of the last three `v3` values, i.e, `89+9+6=104`. Likewise, the row having `date=06` must be equal to `9+6+9=24`. This have to be done for each id and for each date.

This is the desired result:

```
  id  date v3  summarystory
  -------------------------
  1    03  89     NULL
  1    04  9      NULL
  1    05  6      104
  1    06  9      24
  1    07  0      15
  2    03  9      NULL
  2    04  90     NULL
  2    05  6      105
  2    06  9      105
  2    07  10     25
```

- VcountYN:= the number of Y for each row (based only on variables `v1` and `v2`). So. for instance, for the first row it would be VcountYN=1. This variable must be computed for all the rows.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do the computations. Turning it into the new table is left as an exercise:

```
-- SQL 2012 version
Select
  t.id,
  t.[date],
  Case When [Date] Between 5 And 7 Then 
    Sum(v3) over (
      partition by 
        id 
       order by 
         [date]
       rows between 
         2 preceding and current row
    ) Else Null End,
  Case When v1 = 'Y' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When v2 = 'Y' Then 1 Else 0 End
From
  table1 t;

-- SQL 2005 version
Select
  t1.id,
  t1.[date],
  Case When t1.[date] Between 5 And 7 Then t1.v3 + IsNull(t2.v3, 0) + IsNull(t3.v3, 0) Else Null End,
  Case When t1.v1 = 'Y' Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When t1.v2 = 'Y' Then 1 Else 0 End
From
  table1 t1
    Left Outer Join
  table1 t2
    On t1.id = t2.id and t1.[date] = t2.[date] + 1
    Left Outer Join
  table1 t3
    On t2.id = t3.id and t2.[date] = t3.[date] + 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1c45/2